# [NodeJS]: Redirected after a route > a function called before redirect > can we redirect after function call?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes

I have a route as below,

```
router.get('/startjob', function(req, res) {
    var = "one";
    start();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

My start function goes through a loop and needs to redirect to homepage,

```
start(){
    check = setInterval(function(){
        if(//condition){
            var = "two";
            clearInterval(check);
            // redirect to '/'
        }
    },5000);
}
```

Why i wanted to make a redirection twice is because, i wanted to refresh the variables rendered on the home page immediately after the route and also at the end of start() function

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { 
            title: 'Home',
            value: var
        });
}
```

As i have already made a redirect in the route before function ends, i am not able to make a redirection to homepage inside the function.

The only solution i could find was to not make a redirection inside the function and make the page refresh every 5 seconds or so, which i don't feel is wright.

Is there a work around for a redirection inside the function as well ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `node-schedule` or `node-cron` to run the `start()` function every 5 seconds and you can redirect it accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

What I can infer from your question is that you wanna redirect to a new page at the start & end of the start() function. Let me know if the below is working.

```
router.get('/startjob', function(req, res) {
    var = "one";
    start(res);       
}

start(res){
    res.redirect('/');
    check = setInterval(function(){
        if(//condition){
            var = "two";
            clearInterval(check);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    },5000);
}
```

Comment: This won't work as we cannot have a second redirect on the response. This will throw the error ' can't set the headers after they are sent '. What i did for now is - set a variable in the if block and do an ajax to check the variable value and refresh the page accordingly using javascript in ajax. Anyways thanks for the help